# Validar las OPTION de un campo SELECT con JavaScript para que según la opción seleccionada OCULTE un BUTTON del formulario

Tags: javascript, validación, html-select

estoy intentando hacer esto de varías formas pero no logro obtener el resultado que necesito.

Tengo un formulario en 2 partes, uno con el atributo display `NONE` y otro con display `BLOCK`, en el primer formulario (display: `BLOCK`) tengo un `SELECT` que pregunta por el "estado" del trabajador que se quiere registrar, si la opción es "jubilado" o "proceso jubilación" el formulario no debe modificarse y al terminar de llenar los campos agregues al trabajador con el botón "AGREGAR".

[image: Pregunta]

Ahora, donde he tenido problemas es como validar las `OPTION` con JavaScript para que, si la opción seleccionada no es "jubilado" o "proceso jubilación", sino "Activo" el botón "AGREGAR" cambié su atributo de `visible` a `hidden` y en su lugar lo reemplace otro botón que se encuentra en `hidden` que continuará con la siguiente parte del formulario.

```
<label> Estado del Trabajador:
     <div class="slct">
            <select name="Estado" id="estadotrab" required>
                <option value="0" disabled selected>...</option>
                <option value="1">Activo</option>
                <option value="2">Jubilado</option>
                <option value="3">Proceso Jubilación</option>
                <option value="4">Discapacidad</option>
                <option value="5">otro</option>
            </select>
     </div>
</label>

<input type="reset" value="Vaciar Datos" class="button" id="vaciar-datos">
<input type="submit" value="Agregar" class="buttonA" id="btnAgregar">
<input type="button" value="Siguiente" class="buttonS" id="btnSiguiente">
```

Quiero aclarar que el botón "SIGUIENTE" funciona como debe y cambia el atribulo del Formulario 1 `BLOCK` a `NONE` y del formulario 2 de `NONE` A `BLOCK`, pero el cambio de botón "AGREGAR" por "SIGUIENTE" cuando seleccionas una opción del `SELECT` es lo que no logro hacer. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme? De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te refieres a algo asi
//Esta se ejecuta cada ves que se cambia una opción del select

```
 document.getElementById('estadotrab').addEventListener('change', function() {
          if(this.value==='Activo') //si la opcion seleccionada es activo
            {
            document.getElementById('btnAgregar').hide(); //oculta el boton agregar
            document.getElementById('btnSiguiente').show();//muestra el boton siguiente
            }
            else // en caso contrario, que sea jubilado etc
            {
            document.getElementById('btnAgregar').show(); //muestra el boton agregar
            document.getElementById('btnSiguiente').hide(); //oculta el boton siguiente
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <label> Estado del Trabajador:
        <div class="slct">
            <select onchange="cambioopcion(this.value)" name="Estado" id="estadotrab" required>
                <option value="0" disabled selected>...</option>
                <option value="1">Activo</option>
                <option value="2">Jubilado</option>
                <option value="3">Proceso Jubilación</option>
                <option value="4">Discapacidad</option>
                <option value="5">otro</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </label>

    <input type="reset" value="Vaciar Datos" class="button" id="vaciar-datos">
    <input type="submit" value="Agregar" class="buttonA" id="btnAgregar">
    <input type="button" value="Siguiente" class="buttonS" id="btnSiguiente">

    <script>
    function cambioopcion(valor){
       if(valor==1){
          document.getElementById('btnAgregar').hide(); 
          document.getElementById('btnSiguiente').show();
       }else{
          document.getElementById('btnAgregar').show(); 
          document.getElementById('btnSiguiente').hide(); 
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Se agrega al input tipo SELECT el evento ONCHANGE, esta se acciona cunado hay un cambio de selección del mismo, se crea y se adjunta en el evento "ONCHANGE" una función de JAVASCRIPT llamada CAMBIOOPCION, esta será la encargada  de hacer el procedimiento que se requiere